# How to filter a queryset of objects created more than one hour ago from Django's DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, datetime

**Problem**:

I'm trying to filter a model where the status has not changed in over an hour.

**What I've tried**:

```
Product.objects.filter(
                Q(status="PENDING"),
                Q(created__hour__gt=1)
            ).all().order_by("-created")
```

**Expected Solution**:
Get a queryset of objects whose status is "PENDING" but has not changed in more than one hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Product.objects.filter(
    status="PENDING", created__lt=Now()-timedelta(hours=1)
).order_by('-created')
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but please can you explain what `Now()-timedelta(hours=1)` does?

Comment: @PercySherlock: it is an expression that will at SQL level convert to the current timestamp minus one hour. We thus retrieve records where the time stamp is less (so earlier) than that timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the below query for this purpose:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
one_hour_ago =  now - timezone.timedelta(hours=1)
Product.objects.filter(status="PENDING", created__lt=one_hour_ago).order_by('-created')
```